# Confused About Data Sources

Tags: deployment, reporting-services, datasource

When we work on an SSRS report on our local laptops, we have a data source we use. However, when we put the report on our SSRS server, we'd like to be able to specify a different data source.

So, when we upload our report to the SSRS server, we specify a different data source. But, when we run the report, it gives us an error saying it cannot connect to the data source we were using locally. Are we doing something wrong? Or can't this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the datasource for SSRS reports once they are deployed.

On SQL 2005, go to `http://<yourSSRSserver>/reports` and select the report. Select the properties tab at the top of the page, then "data sources" on the right-hand side. I'm not sure if the details for SQL 2008 are the same.

If you need to use the same datasource across many reports (or many report projects, for that matter) the best solution is to use a shared data source, which can be configured once on the server.

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159728.aspx) should give you a starting point.